# Case in order by ignored

Tags: mysql

`ORDER BY CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(),'%w') = 0 THEN 'day DESC' ELSE 'day ASC' END, orderby ASC`

Pretty simple query, always sort by day, if today is sunday then sort descending, if not then sort ascending. But it's always being ignored and only sorts by the `orderby` field.

Comment: You're doing it wrong. You can't specify the sort direction inside the statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want something like:

```
ORDER BY
  CASE
    WHEN DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(),'%w') = 0
      THEN `day` 
    END DESC,
  CASE
    WHEN DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(),'%w') <> 0
      THEN `day` 
    END ASC, 
  `orderby` ASC
```